# Pandas DataFrame fuzzy/closest match merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, fuzzywuzzy

I have a Pandas DataFrame 1 (snippet below):

[df 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuYLZ.png)

I have generated another Dataframe 2 with some similar headings.
I need to match up and merge the rows in both df's under the columns 
"Date" (datetime object), Latitude and Longitude (integers).

I am aware of python's fuzzywuzzy module, but unsure of it's use.

Comment: Can you post actual data/examples?

Comment: Use `np.isclose`,

Comment: go check `pandas.merge_asof` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof or library `fuzzywuzzy`